# Difference between public static and private static variables

Tags: java, variables, static, private, public

```
class Employee{
 // salary  variable is a private static variable
private static double salary;

// DEPARTMENT is a constant
 public static final String DEPARTMENT = "Development";

public static void main(String args[]){
   salary = 1000;
  System.out.println(DEPARTMENT+  "  average salary:"+salary);
}
}
```

This java program contains a static variable. But I cannot understand the difference between public and private static variables.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A public variable is accessible *everywhere* in the code - a private variable is only accessible within the class itself. In this case you're using `Employee.salary` within the `Employee` class, so that's fine.

Note that the variable being static is a completely separate matter - and methods and classes have accessibility in the same way as variables.

There are other levels of access available too - `protected` and the default "package" access (which can't be specified explicitly). See [section 6.6 of the Java Language Specification for more details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6).

(As a side matter, it's also worth learning about what `static` means - you almost certainly *don't* want these variables to be statics, as they apply to *each* `Employee` rather than the `Employee` concept in general. It's odd for `DEPARTMENT` to be a constant here, too.)

Comment: I donot think we ever need private static variables

Comment: @Sameer: I *completely* disagree. While I tend to dislike static variables in general, I would certainly not claim that they're *never* needed. Are the only static variables that you ever use constants? (Even constants can be better off as private, sometimes...)

Comment: @JonSkeet If I use private static variable then will it get memory when app(Android App for example) gets started even though class not instantiate? as like public static variable gets memory?

Comment: @Dharmendra: Yes, public/private makes no difference in terms of memory.

Comment: @AustinWBryan: Just because a word *can* be used as a keyword doesn't mean it should always be specified in code font in Markdown. In this case, both public and static make more sense to be read as regular words, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay, thanks, I'll consider that next time. So when should a keyword be used in code markdown?

Comment: @AustinWBryan: When you're referring to the keyword rather than the concept, basically. Sometimes it's a grey area thoguh.

Answer (score 31):

- A `public` variable is accessible from anywhere (well, anywhere where the class is accessible).
- A `private` variable is only accessible inside the class.
- A `static` variable belongs to the class rather than to an instance of a class.
- Notice that the variable `DEPARTMENT` is also `final`, which means that it cannot be modified once it is set. This is important here because that's what saves this from being bad code -- the variable is a constant so it's okay to give things outside the class access to it.

Comment: GREAT.I have a confusion on final.

Answer (score 3):

```
private static double salary
```

is available only within the class and can be accessed as

```
salary or Employee.salary
```

While

```
 public static final String DEPARTMENT
```

Could be accessed from outside of this class too as follows

```
Employee.DEPARTMENT
```

Answer (score 3):

`public static` - can be accessed from within the class as well as outside the class.

`private static` - can be access from within the class only.

Static's are considered to be anti-OO in OOPS.

```
class Dog
{
    public static string X;
    private static string y;
}
```

`y` can be accessed only from inside `Dog` via either `Dog.y` or just `y`. 
`X` can be accessed anywhere via `Dog.X` or, if you're either in the class or using `using static Dog` as a header, just `X`.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you cannot access `private` static variable from outside the class, and you can access `public` static variable from everywhere.

Comment: Have a look again.The variable salary is private.but if it is private how can the this line" public static void main(String args[]){
   salary = 1000;" access salary?

Comment: @Androidmaid: Because you're accessing it from within the same class (Employee).

Comment: with today computer/technology, a small amt of memory wont do any harm