# Java Swing - manipulation of GUI

Tags: java, swing, events, components

I've got probably trivial problem but I've spent hours in looking for answer.

I would like to create a button (ENTER button) that once clicked, removes certain components on the GUI (like numpad). The problem is that the class that defines instructions to do once button clicked doesn't see the components. I've tried to add `implements ATM` to this class but then the console returned very weird errors (when executing). Is there any 'clean' way to do this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ATM extends JFrame{

// Container
int state = 0; // PIN screen

// ELEMENTS
JPanel container = new JPanel();
JTextArea display = new JTextArea("Please enter your PIN", 10, 50);
JTextField inputArea = new JTextField("");
JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
JButton one = new JButton("1");
JButton two = new JButton("2");
JButton three = new JButton("3");
JButton four = new JButton("4");
JButton five = new JButton("5");
JButton six = new JButton("6");
JButton seven = new JButton("7");
JButton eight = new JButton("8");
JButton nine = new JButton("9");
JButton zero = new JButton("0");
JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");

// EVENTS
ButtonPresser buttonPress = new ButtonPresser(inputArea, display);
EnterPresser enterPress = new EnterPresser(inputArea, display, state, buttons);

ATM(){
super("ATM Cash Machine");
buildGUI();
pack();
setVisible(true);
}

private void buildGUI(){

  // EVENT BINDINGS
  one.addActionListener(buttonPress);
  two.addActionListener(buttonPress);
  three.addActionListener(buttonPress);
  four.addActionListener(buttonPress);
  five.addActionListener(buttonPress);
  six.addActionListener(buttonPress);
  seven.addActionListener(buttonPress);
  eight.addActionListener(buttonPress);
  nine.addActionListener(buttonPress);
  zero.addActionListener(buttonPress);
  clear.addActionListener(buttonPress);
  quit.addActionListener(buttonPress);
  enter.addActionListener(enterPress);

  // ELEMENT SETTINGS
  inputArea.setEditable(false);
  display.setEditable(false);

  container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
  container.add(display);
  container.add(inputArea);

    // Numeric pad
    buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,3));
      buttons.add(one);
      buttons.add(two);
      buttons.add(three);
      buttons.add(four);
      buttons.add(five);
      buttons.add(six);
      buttons.add(seven);
      buttons.add(eight);
      buttons.add(nine);
      buttons.add(clear);
      buttons.add(zero);
      buttons.add(enter);
      buttons.add(quit);
  container.add(buttons);

 add(container, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}

// Main method
public static void main(String[] args){
  ATM atm = new ATM();
}
}

class ButtonPresser implements ActionListener{

private JTextField iField;
private JTextArea oArea;

ButtonPresser(JTextField in, JTextArea out){

iField = in;
oArea = out;

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

switch(e.getActionCommand()){
  case "Quit":
    System.exit(0);
    break;
  case "Clear":
    iField.setText("");
    break;
  default:
    String fieldText = iField.getText();
    if(fieldText.length() < 4){
      iField.setText(fieldText+e.getActionCommand());
    }
    break;

 }


}

}
class EnterPresser implements ActionListener{

  private JTextField iField;
 private JTextArea oArea;
private int state;
private JPanel buttons;

private final String PIN = "1234";

EnterPresser(JTextField in, JTextArea out, int st, JPanel but){

iField = in;
oArea = out;
state = st;
buttons = but;

}

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

if(state == 0){
  String fieldText = iField.getText();
  if(fieldText.equals(PIN)){
    iField.setText("");
    state = 1;
    uiState0To1();
  }
}

 }

 public void uiState0To1(){
   buttons.remove(one);
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem is simple. You need some way for your `ButtonPresser` class to talk with your `ATM` class, this is a classic example of an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)

The idea is, you would provide some kind of event notification that your `ButtonPresser` will trigger under certain conditions, then your `ATM` class would listen for those events, it would then decide what it should do based on those events.

**It is not the responsibility of the `ButtonPresser` to modify the state of `ATM`**, just so we're clear.

You're now moving into the realm of [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), which could provide you a means to utilise [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), which will further reduce the overall complexity of your problem, but also isolate responsibility and decouple your code

Answer (score -4):

I am not sure which components you are trying to remove, but your problem is pretty clear. All of the components defined in the ATM class are not public. One way to manipulate these components from other classes would be to set them public.

The simplest way is to declare them as "public static" and reference them statically through the ATM class. Depending on your case you may need multiple instances of ATM, in which case you would not declare them static.

Here is another question with good info: [Difference between public static and private static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459487/difference-between-public-static-and-private-static-variables)

Comment: I always have issues with understanding the static and non-static stuff. It works anyway, thanks!

Comment: It was bad enough that you suggested making the fields `public`, but `static` as well, that's just plain wrong and incredibly bad advice on both counts

Comment: I am not sure how it is wrong. If he wants to manipulate components from his other class then this is one of the ways to do it... There is nothing wrong about my answer.

Comment: Create more then one instance of the component, see how wrong it is then, making the field public removes encapsulation and exposes the component to unfettered modification. Static is not a cross object communication mechanism and its use should be carefully considered and weighted against the problems it creates. The suggestion of public static is short sighted, limiting and unprofessional, it's also encouraging bad habits which better design approaches would solve. The "simple" solution is always the "right" solution

Comment: In his post he is trying to access them statically and failing because the components are not exposed. He is a clear beginner, telling him to redesign his entire example is impractical and does not actually solve his problem. Your post is insightful and has merit, but that does not mean mine is wrong...