# Private, Static, and scope of variables in Java

Tags: java, variables, scope, static, private

In my Java class, we just learned about scope. And by learned I mean it was briefly mentioned once and never spoken of again. Some questions were posted, and I'm having trouble understanding the difference between two pieces of code. The first one:

```
public class Shadow3 {
    private static int i = 99;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

And the second one:

```
public class Shadow4 {
    private int i;
    public void doSomething(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Shadow4().doSomething(9);
    }
}
```

I understand that the error with the first one is not that the variable is declared twice, but I don't understand why the scope of the variable declared in the Shadow class doesn't reach the main method to cause a duplication error. I also understand why in the first piece of code, the variable i cannot be declared as private static when it is then used in the for loop, because the values of i in the for loop are temporary, but I don't understand how then the variable i in the second piece of code is valid, because it is still private.

Comment: I don't think either blocks of code have errors. Why do you think they do? For loops do have temporary variables, scoped to them only. Have you ran these codes? What did you notice?

Comment: Well wow you're totally right. I deleted and remade my class and tried it again, and it worked! I must have missed some other error in my code. Thanks:)

Comment: Here is the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459487/difference-between-public-static-and-private-static-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand why the scope of the variable declared in the Shadow class doesn't reach the main method to cause a duplication error.

The scope of the class variable does reach the main method. But the lesson is on shadowing. There shouldn't be any error.

> the variable i cannot be declared as private static when it is then used in the for loop, because the values of i in the for loop are temporary,

For loop variables are temporary and locally scoped, yes, but your reasoning isn't correct. You can't declare a local variable as `private` or `static`. That's that.

> I don't understand how then the variable i in the second piece of code is valid, because it is still private.

`private` isn't the problem. The variable could be default, protected, or public. The code is still valid. Matter of fact, both code samples appear valid.

In the first, you can reference a static variable with `Shadow3.i`, for the other, you have an instance variable, so within the `doSomething` method, you'd use `this.i` or `Shadow4.this.i`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. I just realized there was a separate error with my code causing it to appear as though private/static was the problem when it was not.